# Why remount fixes the problem but not the fstab?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs, fstab, hibernate

I have dual-booted Linux and Windows which both have access to a local (non-os) NTFS partition shared on /dev/sda5.

Here is how I mount it in fstab file:

```
UUID=D8A0830EA082F1F4   /mnt/files   ntfs   rw,uid=1000,gid=1000   0   0
```

The problem is, whenever I use the fast reboot option, which is a kind of hibernation, on my Windows this partition mounts as readonly on my Linux. So I remount it like this every time and it will become writable again:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda5 /mnt/files
```

So please tell me what is the difference between this command and the one I have in my fstab? how can I fix my fstab to mount as read-write every time without the need to run this command?

Comment: Your approaching it as it was a Ubuntu problem and you couldn't be more wrong about it. If you want to avoid that default (and by design) behavior make sure to disable Fast Startup **in Windows**.

Comment: Fast reboot, as far as I understand, holds the partition mounted on Windows, which is not fully shutdown in hibernation state. It's a frequent problem, and the typical solution is to have fast reboot turned off. It also solves issues where Windows locks up and boots to black screen, at least in my experience. But aside fron that, I don't know details of it, I can only speak from experience.

Comment: @MichaelBay I don't want to disable fast startup in windows. I just want to force the partition to be mounted as read-write every time. Why do I have to do this manually whereas fstab is there to do things automatically?

Comment: That's how it rolls. With fast startup the drive is hibernated and that means you have to force rw. Mounting it ro automatically is for your own (your data) protection.

Comment: @MichaelBay This drive contains no operating system files and the hiberfil.sys file is not in this partition. So I have nothing to protect. I want to force it.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Indeed. Windows may not boot if the system partition is written from outside but in this case the user wants to access a non-system partition that, being NTFS, is hybernated by that Windows feature as well. It shouldn't prevent booting Windows afterwards but chkdsk may need to run to correct errors.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee It doesn't matter where `hiberdil.sys` is located, but what matters is that it saves state of the whole system.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I don't have anything related to the current state of my system in THIS partition after Windows has shut down.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee  well, we already told you the solution, but you don't wanna listen. **shrug**

Comment: Again, Windows *saves the the state of the whole system*. There's no point in making this a forum like discussion (AU is NOT a forum). You have two options: 1. Disable Fast Startup and use it normally or 2. Don't disable it and keep doing things as you do now (until something breaks). Period, end of discussion, nothing else to say. I would like to ... Selena Gomez but I can't have that either.

Comment: even if there are not system files, writing to a partition that is hibernated in windows can cause file corruption, since windows will see the partition as it was before writing to it from linux. also windows uses some of all drive for swap file unless specifically told not to

Comment: @ravery,@MichaelBay,@Sargiy Kolodyazhnyy Will the same thing happen on an exfat partition?

Comment: yes if it is mounted when windows hibernates --- fast startup is a hibernation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remount doesn't fix the problem. It may even make the situation worse.

Here is what is happening:

1. Windows hibernates while keeping that partition mounted
2. Ubuntu boots, finds out that the partition hasn't been unmounted properly and mounts it read only. This is a safety feature and it is for your own good.
3. You remount it read/write and perhaps start writing to it.

What is not obvious:

1.a. Windows kept an in-memory cache of the filesystem state which said that (figuratively speaking) sector 789 is free

1.b. That in-memory cache has been stored in the hibernation file.

4. Ubuntu writes a new file to sector 789 - it is free after all.
5. You reboot to Windows and it loads its state from the hibernation file.
6. You create a new file
7. Windows uses sector 789 to store that new file - after all its cache says that this sector is free.
8. The file you created in Ubuntu (step 4) is now corrupted.

The proper way to solving this is to somehow unmount that partition in Windows before it hibernates and to auto-mount it again on startup.

How to do that and whether it is possible at all is beyond this forum.

Comment: So I guess it is better to convert my NTFS partition to another type. There only remains exfat and fat32.

Comment: Will the same thing happen on an exfat partition?

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee it will (or should) happen on any filesystem that Windows is capable of writing to. It's a safety feature - the OS *should* mark the filesystem as dirty if it is doing something like hibernation. What you should do is turn off fast boot in Windows, so that a "shutdown" becomes a proper shutdown